# How to define a Clifford Gate while given a tableau in Google Cirq?

Tags: cirq, clifford-group

I would like to uniformly sample from the group of random Clifford gates. I am aware of the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.09412 where they have designed the algorithm to do this task and even provided a Python implementation of it. The algorithm outputs a Clifford tableau uniformly sampled from the corresonding Clifford group. I would like to define a Clifford gate with this tableau in Google Cirq - is there any simple way to do that?

Comment: What do you want to do with it in cirq? How many qubits are we talking about here: less than 10? More than 100? This exact method is the one used by [`stim.Tableau.random`](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/wiki/Stim-v1.8-Python-API-Reference#stim.Tableau.random), but there's nothing in `stimcirq` to convert that tableau into a cirq object at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for the response! The number of qubits N to be simulated is ideally of order few hundred with a circuit depth O(N). I most likely do not need anything beyond 3-qubit random Clifford. Within Cirq I guess one possibility might be to use clifford decomposition into a list of 1 and 2 qubit operations (cirq.decompose_clifford_tableau_to_operations: https://github.com/quantumlib/Cirq/blob/v0.14.1/cirq-core/cirq/transformers/analytical_decompositions/clifford_decomposition.py#L90-L180 ) and create a Clifford Tableau by simply specifying the state - but this sounds like a bit of an overkill...

Comment: @CatQubit There is a way but it's fairly involved. Assuming this is a full tableau (i.e. it has the stabilisers + logicals + destabilisers) then it corresponds to a symplectic matrix. This matrix can be ("Bruhat") decomposed as a product of simpler matrices which are then mapped to clifford circuits (CNOT's + phase + hadarmard). See this for details https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.06987.pdf

Comment: If you're working with hundreds of qubits then you're probably doing a pure stabilizer simulation. In that case I'd recommend giving stim.TableauSimulator a try for your specific problem. Cirq's stabilizer simulation stuff is really minimal, and not optimized for performance. I watch this stack exchange for stim questions so you'd get answers relatively quickly. (That being said, I might be a bit biased since I made stim. But then again I guess I also wrote and drove a large part of cirq. Maybe it all cancels out.)

Comment: @CraigGidney is it then possible to implement say a layer of 2 qubit random Clifford gates between selected qubits in stim? I understand that normally one would use combination of stim.Tableau.random and stim.TableauSimulator().set_inverse_tableau but it does not seem to allow to specify on which qubits I apply these operations and set_inverse_tableau overwrites the previous number of qubits I might have had. 
Furthermore, is there any way to bypass the stim limitation and apply a non-Pauli gate as a feedback? I do not require this latter operation to be efficient neccesarily.

Comment: Huh. I thought there was an exposed method to apply a tableau to qubits but guess not. Will have to fix that. You'd have to pull the simulator's tableau state out, use `stim.Tableau.append` on to apply the random operation, then put the state back in. Which is not very efficient. The tableau simulator doesn't have the Pauli gate limitation on feedback, because you can drive it with python (e.g. write `if m1: sim.h(q)`).

Comment: @CraigGidney, thanks - the implicit method you have described in stim seems to work and drop in efficiency is not significant for my purposes. I think I found a way to circumvent the above issue in cirq as well (though indeed it is way slower than in stim) - will add the answer to the above question after some extra testing. Finally, is there any method in stim.TableauSimulator() which would allow for multiqubit measurement (in a sense of Z_0Z_1 on Bell state returning single 0 or 1 with 50:50)? (I could not find anything in the docs; that would be something akin to cirq.PauliMeasurementGate).

Comment: @CatQubit that's the `MPP` instruction in a circuit. The simulator was made before it so you get at it via `sim.do(circuit)` with a circuit that contains one. There's also `sim.peek_observable`.

Comment: @CraigGidney great - thank you so much - I think it works now. Just one more thing regarding cirq: is there any method equivalent to stim sim.current_measurement_record() while working within simulate_moment_steps of cirq.Simulator? I do not seem to be able to get measurement outcomes from the in-circuit measurements (non-Clifford gate simulation) and method sample_measurement_ops of cirq.SparseSimulatorStep does not seem to do the job...

Comment: @CatQubit I don't think so, but I might be wrong.